# Board Support Package

Tags: embedded, windows-ce

Currently our BSP is built using Visual Studio 2005.  I would like to update this to use VS 2010 at the very least, preferably 2012.  I have not been able to find anything that will allow me to do this.  I tried to upgrade the project to VS 2008, but it failed to load the project.  I was wondering if anybody had some ideas or could at least point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Visual Studio 2008** does support the Platformbuilder Plugin and creating Applications for Win CE, however the import wizard is not perfect, you may need to change some settings by hand.

**Visual Studio 2010** does not support creating BSPs or applications for Win CE.

**Visual Studio 2012** will support creating of BSPs and applications for Windows Embedded Compact 2013. 
It also includes a new faster version of the .Net Compact Framework.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows-embedded/archive/2012/11/14/windows-embedded-compact-v-next-uncovered.aspx

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2012-Virtual-Launch/Visual-Studio-2012-support-for-Windows-Embedded-Compact